# iOS simulator‘s home is black

Tags: simulator, xcode7

Something happened to my simulator, i can't see anything but a black background in my simulator home page.
My environment:Xcode7, OSX10.10.5, all simulators with iOS9.0
[image: Simulator screenshot]

I have already clicked the menu:Hardware->Home

Tks for any response.

Comment: Try `cmd+q` on the simulator and then re-launch it.

Comment: @moonie I have already tried, re-launch,  reboot, restart my computer......

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem just reseting content and settings.

On the Simulator menu, go to Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...